# How should the Ignite node autodiscovery on Google Cloud be enabled

Tags: ignite

I deployed my instance using the steps on https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/google-compute-deployment
and made some configuration changes to enable cloud storage based discovery.
I think I have to specify an optional lib to get the cloud storage discovery module on the classpath, but specifying the OPTION_LIBS variable so that it includes 'ignite-gce' does not have any effect in my case. The logs of the docker container say this:
```

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:966)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:387)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:673)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:874)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:783)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:653)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:622)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration#0' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1f021e6c' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] while setting bean property 'discoverySpi'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1f021e6c' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder#68ceda24' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder] while setting bean property 'ipFinder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder#68ceda24' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi#1f021e6c' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder#68ceda24' of type [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder] while setting bean property 'ipFinder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder#68ceda24' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder#68ceda24' defined in URL [https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.gce.TcpDiscoveryGoogleStorageIpFinder]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractInputStreamContent
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 38 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=https://storage.googleapis.com/ignite-discovery/default-config.xml]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
```

```
What should I do in order to make the docker container pick up this OPTION_LIBS variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually `OPTION_LIBS`, not `OPTIONAL_LIBS`.

Comment: Thank you. That was a mistake, but fixing this did not solve the issue. It still fails in the same way after correcting this. My docker run command is: `docker run -d --net=host  -e OPTION_LIBS=ignite-gce -e CONFIG_URI=secret_url ignite`

Comment: Yup, it's reproduced in my environment too. I'll file a ticket and let you know, if it's really a bug.